# ValidationError: UglifyJS Plugin Invalid Options

Tags: javascript, webpack

```js
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
    }
    ///
    plugins : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            mangle: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
                pure_getters: true,
                unsafe: true,
                unsafe_comps: true,
                screw_ie8: true
            },
            output: {
                comments: false,
            },
            exclude: [/\.min\.js$/gi] // skip pre-minified libs
        }),
// ...
```

My bundle size is 8.6 Mb. I need to resize it to 1-3 Mb. How can I do it if my plugin gives me an error `Unresolved type UglifyJsPlugin`?

[image: Erro message]

Answer (score 0):

You should not use it as plugin: `plugins : [new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({`

Also you have used wrong structure. According to [UglifyJS Webpack Plugin docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) your options should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    mangle: true,
                    warnings: false,
                    compress: {
                        pure_getters: true,
                        unsafe: true,
                        unsafe_comps: true,
                        //screw_ie8: true, // no such option in uglify
                    },
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                    },
                },
                exclude: [/\.min\.js$/gi] // skip pre-minified libs
            }),
        ],
    },
};
```

[If you have any other questions please read the docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin)